# all variables are undefined in python debugger

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pdb

I'm facing a very strange issue on Python 3.6. In the middle of my code, I call `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to debug some code.

And then I'm not able to debug properly, for instance:

```
(Pdb) abc = 3
(Pdb) [abc for _ in range(2)]
*** NameError: name 'abc' is not defined
(Pdb) [abc, abc]
[3, 3]
```

It seems like whenever I use list comprehensions, there is an issue of variable not defined. However, if I call the debugger right after I open Python, I do not observe this behavior, everything runs fine.

Any ideas why I'm having this issue?

Comment: There is work around to execute the command likc this. `eval("(lambda: x)()", vars())`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because list comprehensions are (mostly) evaluated in a nested scope, and nested scopes created in pdb can't access the local variables of the scope being inspected. They can access globals, though, and when you launch pdb immediately after opening Python, you're running it in a global scope, so the `abc` you create is global.

This also happens with list comprehensions in `exec` and in class statements. Unfortunately, there isn't really a better workaround than "don't use list comprehensions there".

Comment: Is this specific to Python 3? I do not observe the issue with Python 2.

Comment: @dhokas: List comprehensions aren't evaluated in a nested scope in Python 2. I believe you'll still see it with genexps and dict/set comprehensions in Python 2, though.

Answer (score 10):

This is filed as [b.p.o. issue #21161](https://bugs.python.org/issue21161), but closed as "won't fix".

The root issue is exactly what [user2357112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48197521/908494) says: Comprehensions<sup>1</sup> work by defining and then running a hidden nested function, but functions defined in pdb inside a frame aren't real nested functions and can't access variables from the frame's scope.

There are workarounds (some of which are mentioned in the b.p.o issue, or places linked from that issue), but they're all just clever variations on one of these:

- `(lambda abc: [abc for _ in range(2)])(abc)` (In other words, define a function and explicitly pass the locals' values as arguments instead of capturing them.)
- `[abc_ for abc_ in [abc] for _ in range(2)]` (In other words, use the fact that the outermost iterable is an argument.<sup>2</sup>)
- `[loc['abc'] for loc in [locals()] for _ in range(2)]` (In other words, use `locals()['name']` instead of `name`, and get the locals passed as above.)
- Use `exec` plus any of the known just-as-horrible workarounds for comprehensions in `exec`.
- Don't use a comprehension, as user2357112 suggests.

---

<sub>1. In Python 2.x, this is not true for list comprehensions, only set and dict comprehensions and generator expressions. But Python 3 changed list comprehensions to make them consistent with the others.</sub>

<sub>2. The hidden nested function for a comprehension captures *almost* all names from the enclosing scope—but the outermost iterable (the one in the first `for`) is special; it's actually a parameter to the hidden function, and the expression is evaluated in the enclosing scope and passed as the argument value.</sub>

Comment: `[locals()['abc'] for _ in range(2)]` doesn't work - the workarounds involving `locals()` need to call `locals` in the outer scope, not inside the comprehension's scope.

Comment: @user2357112 Oops, you're right; you need to pass in a locals dict; I'll edit.

Comment: So confusing when you are trying to debug an issue, and the debugger works differently to your the code. Now you have to debug the debugger. I hope this gets fixed.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the following code:

```
(Pdb) !import code; code.interact(local=vars())
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 17:14:51) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> [abc for _ in range(2)]
```

Use Ctrl-D to return to the regular pdb prompt.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Panfeng Li's answer, but a simpler way to do this is to use `interact` in pdb.

What follows is an example of pdb failing and `interact` working in the same context.

```js
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  4 2017, 06:09:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def do_comp():
...   abc = 3
...   import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
...
>>> do_comp()
--Return--
> <stdin>(3)do_comp()->None
(Pdb) [abc for _ in range(2)]
*** NameError: name 'abc' is not defined
(Pdb) interact
*interactive*
>>> [abc for _ in range(2)]
[3, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this simplified version 