# Fibonacci function can not recurse - NameError: name 'fib' is not defined

Tags: python, function, recursion, ipython, fibonacci

When using an embeddded interpreter

```
>>> import IPython
>>> IPython.embed()

In [1]: def fib(n):
   ...:    if n <= 1:
   ...:        return n
   ...:    else:
   ...:        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
   ...:
In [2]: fib(2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 fib(2)

Cell In[1], line 5, in fib(n)
      3     return n
      4 else:
----> 5     return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

NameError: name 'fib' is not defined
```

Expected output:

```
In [2]: fib(2)
Out[2]: 1
```

It gets `NameError: name 'fib' is not defined`, but the name was defined just before. Why isn't the function functioning?

Comment: Looks like this has been a known issue since 2010: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/136 but this stackoverflow answer has a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67517617/6273251