# Python: Test if a string in a string in a list comprehension (not working in PDB only)

Tags: python, pdb

I am trying to test if some words are in a sentence, as per the code below. Unfortunately the first `in` I would like to mean:

- test if the sentence contains x,
- But I think its taking it as sentence is looping over something.

How does one correct the below code:

Very confused, in a new terminal it works:

```py
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> words = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> sentence = 'Some sentence bar the beach'
>>> match = any(x in sentence for x in words)
>>> match
True
```

But in a pdb it doesnt:

```
(Pdb) words = ['foo', 'bar']
(Pdb) words
['foo', 'bar']
(Pdb) sentence = 'Some sentence bar the beach'
(Pdb) sentence
'Some sentence bar the beach'
(Pdb) match = any(x in sentence for x in words)
*** NameError: name 'sentence' is not defined
(Pdb)
```

Okay I see the code is working, but not in the `pdb`, what is the gotcha with the `pdb`?

Comment: Why do you think this is incorrect?

Comment: Split it by spaces: sentence.split()

Comment: This returns true

Comment: Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes you are technically looping over `sentence` when you check for presence of `x` although this is done in the background. This code works fine for the case you present.

Comment: `words` **isn't** a list-comprehension, just a list

Comment: Hmm, surprising, cause it says for me the equivalent of 'sentence' is not defined (in my real codE) ... okay there must be a difference between my real code and minimum reproducible exmaple, will do some more digging...

Comment: @run_the_race post the error traceback. Maybe that will help us know what is the issue.

Comment: Added exactly pdb interaction to illustrate the problem

Comment: Interesting situation. Seems to be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48197521/5225301

Answer (score -1):

This will give you a list of all matching words

`match = [x for x in words if x in sentence]`